# Angular load json file dynamically onclick

Tags: json, url, dynamic, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple page that displays a list of items. Data is pulled from a JSON file (URL is provided by the server).

Two tabs allow to display (onclick) the "most recent" or the "popular" items (again data of each tab will is provided via JSON file). By default the "most recent" items should be displayed.

What is the best way to load the right JSON file onclick and display its content.

I was thinking of passing the URLs in the markup (but I doubt that's the best way to do it). What I had in mind:

**HMTL**

```
<ul>
  <li jsrc="recentitems.json" urlgetter>Most recent</li>
  <li jsrc="popularitems" urlgetter>Most popular</li>
</ul>
```

Plunker of my code: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/glSz1qytmdZ9BQfGbmVo?p=preview

Any suggestions on how to approach it?

**EDIT**

I'm slightly changing my approach. I'm now making one HTTP request (hopefully also better performance wise?). 
Basically I'd like to load all the items once then filter/sort them.

Expanding from your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/glSz1qytmdZ9BQfGbmVo?p=preview 
I added a "date" & "views" attributes to the object item (see JSON).

1. **Tabs**
   -- How could I filter/sort the items onclick? "Recent" would be sorted by date and "Popular" would be sorted by views.
2. **Categories**
   -- I'm using ng-click to grab the category value although not sure how to update the filter dynamically (using the value passed onclick).

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to do something like:-

First the HTML:-

```
   <div ng-app="App">
      <div ng-controller="tabsCtrl">
         <ul>
            <li ng-click="tab(1)">Recent items</li>
            <li ng-click="tab(2)">Popular items</li>
         </ul>
         <ul>
            <li ng-repeat='product in products'>{{product.Name}}</li>
         </ul>
         {{products || json}}
      </div>
   </div>
```

and the JS

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.factory('products', function ($http, $q) {
      return {
         items: function (url) {
            //create our deferred object.
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            //make the call.
            $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
               //when data is returned resolve the deferment.
               deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function () {
               //or reject it if there's a problem.
               deferred.reject();
            });

            //return the promise that work will be done.
            return deferred.promise;
         }
      }
   });

app.controller("tabsCtrl", function ($scope, products) {
   $scope.products = products.items('/api/products');

   $scope.tab = function (tabIndex) {
      if (tabIndex == 1)
         $scope.products = products.items('/api/products');
      if (tabIndex == 2)
         $scope.products = products.items('/api/popularproducts');
   };
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. First of all thanks for your response. I slightly changed my approach after second thought. My original idea was to get one JSON file from the server for each tab (most recent & most popular) but since Angular filter seems to be quite powerful I'd like to take advantage of it. I have a few more questions - hope that's ok. See my **EDIT**; also added some comments to my updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/glSz1qytmdZ9BQfGbmVo?p=preview

Comment: Urm, in reality the answer is exactly what you originally asked for. Really you should ask another question for your edits as it has changed drastically. I am sorry you didn't reward my efforts. I wish you luck

Comment: No problem. I thought it was Ok to ask here since it's related but I'll ask a new question then. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Patrice It's pretty poor form to not even upvote/mark his answer as correct after he took the time to code all of that for you.